# JProgressbar width using Grid/FlowLayout

Tags: java, swing, grid-layout, flowlayoutpanel, border-layout

I'm working on a downloader which looks like this at the moment:

[image: Screenshot]

The JFrame uses a BorderLayout.
In the NORTH, I have a JPanel(FlowLayout). In the SOUTH there is also a JPanel(FlowLayout), in the WEST I just have a JTextArea (in a JScrollPane). This is all shown correctly. However, in the EAST I currently have a JPanel(GridLayout(10, 1)).

I want to show up to 10 JProgressBars in the EAST section which are added and removed from the panel dynamically. The problem is, I can not get them to look like I want to them to look: I want the JProgressBars' width to fill up the entire EAST section because 1) This gives the app a more symmetrical look and 2) The ProgressBars may contain long strings that don't fit at the moment. I've tried putting the JPanel that contains the GridLayout(10, 1) in a flowlayout and then put that flowlayout in the EAST section, but that didn't work either.

My code (SSCCE) is currently as follows:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DownloadFrame();
    }

    private static class DownloadFrame extends JFrame {

        private JButton downloadButton;
        private JTextField threadIdTextField;
        private JTextArea downloadStatusTextArea;
        private JScrollPane scrollPane;
        private JTextField downloadLocationTextField;
        private JButton downloadLocationButton;

        private JPanel North;
        private JPanel South;
        private JPanel ProgressBarPanel;

        private Map<String, JProgressBar> progressBarMap;

        public DownloadFrame() {
            InitComponents();
            InitLayout();
            AddComponents();
            AddActionListeners();

            setVisible(true);
            setSize(700, 300);
        }

        private void InitComponents() {
            downloadButton = new JButton("Dowload");
            threadIdTextField = new JTextField(6);
            downloadStatusTextArea = new JTextArea(10, 30);
            scrollPane = new JScrollPane(downloadStatusTextArea, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
            downloadLocationTextField = new JTextField(40);
            downloadLocationButton = new JButton("...");
            North = new JPanel();
            South = new JPanel();
            ProgressBarPanel = new JPanel();
            progressBarMap = new HashMap<String, JProgressBar>();
        }

        private void InitLayout() {
            North.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            South.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            ProgressBarPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 1));
        }

        private void AddComponents() {
            North.add(threadIdTextField);
            North.add(downloadButton);
            add(North, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            add(ProgressBarPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

            South.add(downloadLocationTextField);
            South.add(downloadLocationButton);
            add(South, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.WEST);
        }

        private void AddActionListeners() {
            downloadButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    addNewProgessBar(threadIdTextField.getText());
                }
            });
        }

        public void addNewProgessBar(String threadId) {
            JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
            progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
            progressBarMap.put(threadId, progressBar);
            drawProgessBars();
        }

        void drawProgessBars() {
            ProgressBarPanel.removeAll();
            for (JProgressBar progressBar : progressBarMap.values()) {
                ProgressBarPanel.add(progressBar);
            }
            validate();
            repaint();
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

***EDIT***

Easiest solution: change

```
add(ProgressBarPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

to

```
add(ProgressBarPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: Screenshot of GUI]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DownloadFrame();
    }

    private static class DownloadFrame extends JFrame {

        private JButton downloadButton;
        private JTextField threadIdTextField;
        private JTextArea downloadStatusTextArea;
        private JScrollPane scrollPane;
        private JTextField downloadLocationTextField;
        private JButton downloadLocationButton;

        private JPanel North;
        private JPanel South;
        private JPanel ProgressBarPanel;

        private Map<String, JProgressBar> progressBarMap;

        public DownloadFrame() {
            InitComponents();
            AddComponents();
            AddActionListeners();

            pack();
            setVisible(true);
            //setSize(700, 300);
        }

        private void InitComponents() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            downloadButton = new JButton("Dowload");
            threadIdTextField = new JTextField(6);
            downloadStatusTextArea = new JTextArea(10, 30);
            scrollPane = new JScrollPane(downloadStatusTextArea, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
            downloadLocationTextField = new JTextField(40);
            downloadLocationButton = new JButton("...");
            North = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
            South = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
            ProgressBarPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
            ProgressBarPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
            ProgressBarPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,20));
            progressBarMap = new HashMap<String, JProgressBar>();
        }

        private void AddComponents() {
            North.add(threadIdTextField);
            North.add(downloadButton);
            add(North, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            add(ProgressBarPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

            South.add(downloadLocationTextField);
            South.add(downloadLocationButton);
            add(South, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.WEST);
        }

        private void AddActionListeners() {
            downloadButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    addNewProgessBar(threadIdTextField.getText());
                }
            });
        }

        public void addNewProgessBar(String threadId) {
            JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
            progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
            progressBarMap.put(threadId, progressBar);
            drawProgessBars();
        }

        void drawProgessBars() {
            ProgressBarPanel.removeAll();
            for (JProgressBar progressBar : progressBarMap.values()) {
                ProgressBarPanel.add(progressBar);
            }
            validate();
            repaint();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please use the common nomenclature for attribute and method names.  That would be `camelCase`, rather than `EachWordUpperCase`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But I just (after hours of searching, typical) found the easiest way to fix my problem. Add the ProgressBarPanel to CENTER instead of EAST gets the result I'm looking for. *feels stupid for not trying that*

You're right about the naming convention. I will take that in account.

Answer (score 3):

Please post a compilable runnable small program for the quickest best help, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Suggestions include using GridLayout(0, 1) (variable number of rows, one column), or display the JProgressBars in a JList that uses a custom renderer that extends JProgressBar.

**Edit 1:**
I know that Andrew has already posted the accepted answer (and 1+ for an excellent answer), but I just wanted to demonstrate that this can be done readily with a JList, something like so:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class EastProgressList extends JPanel {
   private DefaultListModel myListModel = new DefaultListModel();
   private JList myList = new JList(myListModel);
   private JTextField downloadUrlField = new JTextField(10);

   public EastProgressList() {
      JButton downLoadBtn = new JButton("Download");
      downLoadBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            downloadAction();
         }
      });
      JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
      northPanel.add(new JLabel("File to Download:"));
      northPanel.add(downloadUrlField);
      northPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(15));
      northPanel.add(downLoadBtn);

      myList.setCellRenderer(new ProgressBarCellRenderer());
      JScrollPane eastSPane = new JScrollPane(myList);
      eastSPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());

      add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(20, 30)), BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      add(eastSPane, BorderLayout.EAST);
   }

   private void downloadAction() {
      String downloadUrl = downloadUrlField.getText();
      final MyData myData = new MyData(downloadUrl);
      myListModel.addElement(myData);
      myData.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
         public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            if (evt.getPropertyName().equals(MyData.VALUE)) {
               myList.repaint();
               if (myData.getValue() >= 100) {
                  myListModel.removeElement(myData);
               }
            }
         }

      });
   }

   private class ProgressBarCellRenderer extends JProgressBar implements ListCellRenderer {
      protected ProgressBarCellRenderer() {
         setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));
      }

      public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
               int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
         //setText(value.toString());
         MyData myData = (MyData)value;
         setValue(myData.getValue());
         setString(myData.getText());
         setStringPainted(true);
         return this;
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowUI() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("EastProgressList");
      frame.getContentPane().add(new EastProgressList());
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowUI();
         }
      });
   }
}

class MyData {
   public static final int TIMER_DELAY = 300;
   public static final String VALUE = "value";
   protected static final int MAX_DELTA_VALUE = 5;
   private String text;
   private int value = 0;
   private Random random = new Random();
   private PropertyChangeSupport pcSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

   public MyData(String text) {
      this.text = text;
      new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int deltaValue = random.nextInt(MAX_DELTA_VALUE);
            int newValue = value + deltaValue;
            if (newValue >= 100) {
               newValue = 100;
               ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
            }
            setValue(newValue);
         }
      }).start();
   }

   public String getText() {
      return text;
   }

   public int getValue() {
      return value;
   }

   public void setValue(int value) {
      int oldValue = this.value;
      this.value = value;

      PropertyChangeEvent pcEvent = new PropertyChangeEvent(this, VALUE, oldValue, value);
      pcSupport.firePropertyChange(pcEvent);
   }

   public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener pcListener) {
      pcSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(pcListener);
   }


}
```

This results in a GUI looking like so:
[image]

Comment: and ( @Andrew Thompson ) who did told that here isn't lots of fun +1

Answer (score 3):

well. that possible, but in your example `CENTER` area occupated some `Rectangle`, its hard to reduce/remove `CENTER` area to the zero `Size`

to the North `JPanel` (`BorderLayout`) place another `JPanel` and put it to the EAST (with `LayoutManager` would be `GridLayout(1,2,10,10)`) and put here two `JComponents` `JTextField - threadIdTextField` and `JButton - downloadButton`, there you are needed `setPreferredSize` 1) for `JComponents` (correct way) or 2) for whole `JPanel` (possible way too)

`JScrollPane` with `JTextArea` must be placed to the `CENTER` area

`JPanel` with `JProgressBars` place to `EAST`, but again set same `PreferredSize` as for `JPanel` with `JTextField` and `JButton` from the `NORTH`

`SOUTH JPanel` remains without changes

Comment: Good call on mentioning the preferred size.  Though I took 'option 2' - possible way, rather than 'option 1' - correct way.  "Batteries not included.."  ;)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson then you must hoping that Jeanette or Rob isn't around :-)

Comment: @mKorbel: amen to that, especially kleopatra/Jeanette (though lord knows I respect her abilities beyond compare)!

Comment: @mKorbel  Hey mister, I don't want trouble.  Please don't tell them.  ;)